# Insert image into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, image

I want to insert in a table an `(image , id, Code)` but I don't know how to do this .

What I am looking for is how to insert an image not url.

Comment: I posted my question with an answer here, if anyone needs to know how to do this in a Windows Form: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33962272/153923

Answer (score 23):

you can try like this

```
CREATE TABLE ImageTable
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) ,
    Photo varbinary(max) 
)

INSERT INTO ImageTable (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 1, 'test', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\test.jpg', Single_Blob) as image
```

Comment: but if i put url of the image for exemple in my DD 'D' in a folder ' myimages' , and when the user take this application in the futur he will have a problem whith the path of the image no?

Comment: what if is stored procedure ? how can I do that?